# Python - Rearrange elements in a 3D array

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following Numpy array of shape (4, 4, 3):

```
a = [[[ 0  1  2]
      [ 3  4  5]
      [ 6  7  8]
      [ 9 10 11]]

      [[12 13 14]
       [15 16 17]
       [18 19 20]
       [21 22 23]]

      [[24 25 26]
       [27 28 29]
       [30 31 32]
       [33 34 35]]

      [[36 37 38]
       [39 40 41]
       [42 43 44]
       [45 46 47]]]
```

I am looking for an elegant solution to re-arrange the elements in that array to get the following 3D array of shape (3, 4, 4):

```
a_new = [[[ 0  3  6  9]
          [12 15 18 21]
          [24 27 30 33]
          [36 39 42 45]]

         [[ 1  4  7 10]
          [13 16 19 22]
          [25 28 31 34]
          [37 40 43 46]]

         [[ 2  5  8 11]
          [14 17 20 23]
          [26 29 32 35]
          [38 41 44 47]]]
```

Comment: So basically you want to put all elements from all lists into one and then split them into three step-wise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`np.transpose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) -

```
a.transpose(2,0,1)
```

Or use [`np.rollaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rollaxis.html) -

```
np.rollaxis(a,2,0) # Or np.rollaxis(a,-1,0)
```

Answer (score 2):

In case somebody asks the same question for pure Python:

```
mylist = [[[1,2,3], [4,5,6]], [[7,8,9], [10, 11, 12]]]
flat = sum(sum(mylist, []), [])
groups = 3
print [flat[r::groups] for r in range(groups)]
```

> [[1, 4, 7, 10], [2, 5, 8, 11], [3, 6, 9, 12]]

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way I can think of is to use numpy's `swapaxes` function in combination with the transpose function.

```
anew=np.swapaxes(a,0,1).T
```

Comment: This works too but np.transpose seems to be much faster

Comment: Interesting. You would think that `array.T` is just calling `np.transpose` on `self`, but apparently not. I need to test this some other time.

Comment: Okay. I had 0.00405ms for `array.T` and 0.00095ms for `np.transpose`. Tested it on a bigger array of shape (256, 256, 3)

Comment: @Ehsan With `np.swapaxes(a,0,1).T` we are making two passes of permuting axes, once with the `swapaxes` and then with the transpose (`.T`), whereas `a.transpose(2,0,1)` is just one pass of permuting axes. Hence, the performance difference.

Comment: @Divakar that makes sense. I totally missed that. thanks :)